# Using AppleScript to set borders in Numbers?

Tags: applescript

I've successfully managed to get AppleScript to manipulate the background colors in my Numbers document by refering to the `background color` property. However, I would like to set the borders of a selection or range of cells as well.

I've looked in the Dictionary in AppleScript Editor for a command or property that could help me out here, but I haven't found anything. Is it the case that it's not possible to create borders in Numbers with AppleScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the AppleScript dictionary to allow this functionality (which is awful, IMO, but perhaps Apple will add this in the future if enough people complain).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SystemEvents to interact with the interface of Numbers to add the borders:

```applescript
-- Set the selection range
tell application "Numbers"
    make new document
    tell front document to tell active sheet to tell table 1
        set selection range to range "A3:C6"
    end tell
end tell

-- Asks System Events to interact with the interface
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Numbers"
    -- Asks the main window to click on the button called 'Cell' (the name depends of your system language)
    tell window 1
        click radio button "Cell" of radio group 1

        -- Scroll area 4 is the inspector area
        tell scroll area 4
            -- The first incrementor of the inspector is the borders' one.
            increment incrementor 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

If you want to manipulate other elements of the interface, I recommend using the *Accessibility Inspector* app that comes with Xcode.